# What is record array in pandas?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I found the following code:

```
df.to_records(index=False)
```

I try to figure out what it does. I found [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_records.html) page that says:

> Convert DataFrame to record array. Index will be put in the ‘index’
>   field of the record array if requested

It does not help since I do not know what `record array` means. I print df before and after `to_records`. On the screen I see no difference.

Comment: Are you trying to do something specifically that you think a record array is appropriate for? Or just curious about what record arrays are? [This](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Those are `numpy` record arrays (see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html) and [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html)).  FWIW, I don't use them very much, as I find a `DataFrame` much more convenient for the sorts of operations I need to do on data that I'd bother giving a certain name.  That said, lots of people like them.

It didn't change `df` because `to_records` doesn't change `df` in-place from an object of one type to another, it returns an object of the target type.  Try

```
ra = df.to_records(index=False)
print ra
```

to see what you've made.